# ES6 syntax reference: use spread and boolean short circuiting to conditionally add fields to an object during declaration

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, syntax

I want to construct an object like this:

```
const obj = {
    a: 'a',  // only add this if "someCondition" is true
    b: 'b',  // only add this if "someCondition" is false
    always: 'present', // add this in any case
}
```

This works:

```
const obj = { always: 'present' }
if (someCondition) { obj.a = 'a' }
if (!someCondition) { obj.b = 'b' }
```

However, I'm looking for a more concise way using ES6 syntax.

Comment: Soooo.... you just added a wiki as a Q&A xD If I don't remember bad, there's a section to add manuals and such in Stack Overflow.

Comment: @JorgeFuentesGonzález See [Can I answer my own questions, even if I knew the answer before asking?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/17463/289905) and [Sunsetting Documentation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/354217/4642212).

Comment: Your post is getting downvotes and close votes as “unclear what your asking”. It may help to [edit] your post and formulate an actual question and a problem statement.

Comment: I took the liberty to edit your post to make it fit better in the Q&A format.

Comment: thanks @georg and friends I agree it reads better now

Comment: @zayquan But that don't was a question and an answer. That was my point. Was just a simple tutorial.

Answer (score 4):

It is possible using ES6 syntax to conditionally add fields during declaration of an object.

This is useful if the consumer of the object will not tolerate fields with null / undefined / whatever values, and you do not want to have to write multiple statements to correctly declare the object:

```
const obj = {
  ...(someCondition && {a: 'a'}),
  ...(!someCondition && {b: 'b'}),
  always: 'present'
}
```

So how does that work ? Lets look at `...(true && {a: 'a'})`. The ES6 [spread operator "..."](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) will iterate each of the field->value pairs in { "a": "a" } applying them to x.

The `true && x` expression will return x, whereas `false && x` will return false. This is known as [short circuit evaluation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Short-circuit_evaluation)

So if the logical expression is true then the spread operator will add the fields, and if it is not true it will not add anything.

Comment: The actual reason why no properties are added in the `false` case is because object spread coerces its operand to an object whose own properties are added. `Object(false)` doesn’t have any own properties, same for `Object(42)`, `Object(Symbol("hello"))`, etc. This is quite obscure…