# how to disable all transitions in material UI while under test

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, bdd

I maintain a react app that uses Material UI and a selenium based BDD test suite on top of the app.
I found that some of my tests were intermittently failing on missing/broken CSS selectors, that were targeting elements that were not immediately present due to material UI components executing transitions on open.

I was able to disable transitions, only while under test, using a pretty simple solution. You wont believe the answer ...

Answer (score 1):

There is a setting that can be applied in the Material UI theme that will globally disable transitions

```
const theme = {
    transitions: { create: () => 'none' }
}
```

- In the BDD suite I set a specific user agent.
- In the file that creates the Material UI theme I simply add the disable line if the user agent indicates that this is a BDD test.

So put it all together in the file where you define your Matuerial UI theme:

```
import { createMuiTheme } from '@material-ui/core/styles'

const bddUserAgentString = 'BDD Test'
const isBddRunning = () => global.navigator.userAgent === bddUserAgentString

const theme = createMuiTheme({
  palette: '... omitted ...',
  shadows: '... omitted ...',
  spacing: '... omitted ...',
  typography: '... omitted ...',
  ...(isBddRunning() && { transitions: { create: () => 'none' } }),
})

export default theme
```

If that '...' spread operator syntax is confusing have a look here : [ES6 syntax reference: use spread and boolean short circuiting to conditionally add fields to an object during declaration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58046033/es6-syntax-reference-use-spread-and-boolean-short-circuiting-to-conditionally-a/58046034#58046034)